# Remove anchor from URL MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, anchor, redirecttoaction

So, I have a form on PageA that attaches an anchor so that the page jumps to errors shown on PageA.  But, when there are no errors, I am trying to use

```
return RedirectToAction("PageB", new { id = ID });
```

But, for some reason, even though I am redirecting to a different action, the anchor is being attached.  So, on error it would be going to www.domain.com/Controller/PageA#errors, it goes to www.domain.com/Controller/PageB?id=5#errors.  This causes an issue because there is an anchor errors on PageB also.  How can I remove the anchor on the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it manually, by using Url.RouteUrl (which will create a string with your exact URL).